# How to make (cyr)deliver put messages into mailboxes whose names contain space characters?

Tags: imap, mail-delivery-agent

Since quite a while, I am running Cyrus imapd, which generally works fine. Now, for the first time, I am in a situation where I need to use cyrdeliver (the MDA which comes with Cyrus imapd) to deliver messages into subfolders of mailboxes whose names contain a space character. I am trying to solve this problem for several hours now, but to no avail.

For testing purposes, I have created a user `ton_pp`, and have created two subfolders in her inbox. These subfolders' names are `Health` and `Health Reports`. Having cyradm list the access rights confirms that both folders have the same IMAP permissions:

```
localhost> lam user/ton_pp*
user/ton_pp:
  ton_pp lrswipkxtecda
  cyrus lrswipkxtecda
user/ton_pp/INBOX/Health:
  cyrus lrswipkxtecda
  ton_pp lrswipkxtecda
user/ton_pp/INBOX/Health Reports:
  cyrus lrswipkxtecda
  ton_pp lrswipkxtecda
```

I have created a test message with the following content:

```
root@morn ~ # cat testmessage
From: nobody@nowhere.com
To: somebody@somewhere.com
Subject: Test message

This is a test message.
```

When I execute

```
/usr/sbin/cyrdeliver -a cyrus -m INBOX/Health ton_pp < testmessage
```

the test message immediately appears in the subfolder `Health` of the `INBOX` of the user `ton_pp`. So far, so good - this is what I hoped for.

However, when trying the same with subfolder `Health Reports` (instead of `Health`) I am just getting an error message:

```
root@morn ~ # /usr/sbin/cyrdeliver -a cyrus -m "INBOX/Health Reports" ton_pp < testmessage
ton_pp+INBOX/Health Reports: Bad protocol
```

(The quotes around the mailbox folder name are needed to prevent the shell from splitting it).

This made me research more thoroughly. First, I studied the code of [mbox2cyrus](https://github.com/bartcortooms/sysadmin/blob/master/scripts/mail/cyrus/mbox2cyrus), which uses `cyrdeliver` to transfer messages in `mbox` format to Cyrus imapd. The code is quite understandable; lines 151 through 154 read:

```
# Escape spaces in folder names for cyrdeliver. (Otherwise cyrdeliver
# will exit with the error "Bad protocol").
$subfolder =~ s/ /\\ /g;
$subfolder =~ s/,/\\,/g;
```

Although I am unsure regarding the special meaning of the comma, this clearly shows that it should be sufficient to quote the space character in folder names by prepending it by a backslash. This made the error message go away:

```
root@morn ~ # /usr/sbin/cyrdeliver -a cyrus -m "INBOX/Health\ Reports" ton_pp < testmessage
root@morn ~ #
```

However, `cyrdeliver` now discards the message silently, or puts it somewhere where I can't find it; it appears neither in `INBOX` nor in any of its subfolders.

Then I started to study the IMAP [RFC3501](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#page-81) (especially, the chapters about formal syntax and mailbox naming) and from that got the impression that mailbox names containing special characters (like space characters) should be quoted by double quotes; that is, double quotes should be passed down to `cyrdeliver` in addition. Trying it just brought back the error messages:

```
root@morn ~ # /usr/sbin/cyrdeliver -a cyrus -m '"INBOX/Health\ Reports"' ton_pp < testmessage
ton_pp+"INBOX/Health\ Reports": Bad protocol
root@morn ~ # /usr/sbin/cyrdeliver -a cyrus -m '"INBOX/Health Reports"' ton_pp < testmessage
ton_pp+"INBOX/Health\ Reports": Bad protocol
```

Obviously, it doesn't like the double quotes; quoting (or not) the space character does not change anything. Suspecting that the mixture of an unquoted mailbox / user name and a quoted "subfolder" name could be problematic, I also tried an alternative which is syntactically different, but semantically equivalent, according to `man deliver`:

```
root@morn ~ # /usr/sbin/cyrdeliver -a cyrus -m "user/ton_pp/INBOX/Health Reports" < testmessage
+user/ton_pp/INBOX/Health Reports: Bad protocol
root@morn ~ # /usr/sbin/cyrdeliver -a cyrus -m "user/ton_pp/INBOX/Health\ Reports" < testmessage
+user/ton_pp/INBOX/Health\ Reports: Mailbox does not exist
root@morn ~ # /usr/sbin/cyrdeliver -a cyrus -m '"user/ton_pp/INBOX/Health\ Reports"' < testmessage
+"user/ton_pp/INBOX/Health\ Reports": Bad protocol
root@morn ~ # /usr/sbin/cyrdeliver -a cyrus -m '"user/ton_pp/INBOX/Health Reports"' < testmessage
+"user/ton_pp/INBOX/Health Reports": Bad protocol
```

So this didn't improve anything.

I also found a [bit of information on the website of the Cyrus folks](https://www.cyrusimap.org/3.4/imap/reference/faqs/o-mailbox-doesnotexist.html) and tried to treat the space character as they treat the `@` character in this FAQ. That is, I repeated the tests above with `\\\`  instead of `\` . Again, this didn't work, leading either to the "Mailbox doesn't exist" or to the "Bad protocol" error.

Now I am completely stuck. Could somebody help me out? What do I need to do to make `cyrdeliver` put messages into subfolder of `INBOX`, when these subfolder have spaces in their name?

Comment: Why not just send an email as normal and use sieve to handle the deposit?

Comment: Because the whole system (which actually is administrated by others) is designed the other way around: Actually, mail messages are pulled in via `fetchmail`; fetchmail executes `procmail` as the MDA (many recipes there which are hard to transfer to sieve); `procmail`'s recipes in turn finally execute `cyrdeliver` (at least many of them).